# SendGrid: Missing argument 1 for SendGrid\Email::__construct()

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am sure this is a simple solution, I am attempting to set up a sendgrid to send confirmation emails out.

```
require 'sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php';
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($user,$pass);
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo($sEmail)
      ->setFrom($email)
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

Upon execution of the code i get these error messages:

```
 Warning: Missing argument 1 for SendGrid\Email::__construct()
```

I am running PHP Version 5.6.16

I am sure i have missed something silly

Answer (score 2):

There have been some updates to the SendGrid-PHP library. See the example from the readme : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

```
<?php
// If you are using Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// If you are not using Composer (recommended)
// require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@example.com");
$subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@example.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

You get that error because of `$email = new SendGrid\Email();` which needs two parameters as seen here https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php#L845 which are `$name` and `$email`.

`$name` you can leave `null` if you don't want a From Name.

Also, the use of username and password like `$sendgrid = new SendGrid($user,$pass);` was deprecated, see here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/lib/SendGrid.php#L34

You need to create an API key and use it. See here : https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys

Comment: How can we add attachment here?

Comment: HI there, I just followed the same steps but showing this error: Array{"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}

Answer (score 0):

I was also tackling with similar kind of issue for send grid.

I got it worked by adding following header.

"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf8"